# Questions about Rails render call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When seeing in the code the following lines :

```
<%= render :partial => 'ingredients/form',
           :locals => {:form => recipe_form} %>
```

I wonder what is actually happening.

1. I have noticed `render` is a part of `RenderingHelper`. How do I know which object I can use while writing? How can I use it without `RenderingHelper` prefix as in Java (i.e. `RenderingHelper.render`). Am I inheriting from it in the form view?
2. Since I know Java and C#, I have searched for `ingredients/form` and couldn't find it in the code. I am guessing it is part of the convention over configuration rule. What is it? Where is it defined?
3. Regarding the `:locals => {:form => recipe_form}` line, is that a parameter sent to `render`? Is that double assignment? What does the `=>` operator actually do here?
4. If it is a parameter it was hard to understand from the `render` signature:

   > Returns the result of a render that's dictated by the options hash. The primary options are:
   >
   > - `:partial` - See `ActionView::PartialRenderer`.
   > - `:file` - Renders an explicit template file (this used to be the old default), add `:locals` to pass in those.
   > - `:inline` - Renders an inline template similar to how it's done in the controller.
   > - `:text` - Renders the text passed in out.

Comment: the button at SO says "Ask `a` question" .. look through google

Comment: Each of those bullets should be an entirely different question. Even though they are all based on the same code snippet, they're completely disjoint.

Comment: Regarding your recently deleted question, you must call `start()` on a Thread, not `run()` if you want to run the code in the run method on a different thread. Else no background thread is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please try to ask one question per post.

1. `RenderingHelper` is a module, and its methods are made available via an `include` somewhere. Read more about how Ruby's [modules](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_modules.html) work.
2. Partial filenames are always prfixied with an underscore, your partial will be located in `app/views/ingredients/_form.html.erb`
3. Both `:form` and `:locals` are keys in an options hash being passed to render; The corrpsponding value for `:locals` is a nested hash, which contains one key, `:form` whose value is a local variable named `recipe_form`. This might be more obvious if you explicitly specify some of the optional punctuation:

   ```
   <%= render({:partial => 'ingredients/form', :locals => {:form => recipe_form}}) %>
   ```
4. Ruby (and Rails specifically) use variable length lists of arguments in the form of key/value hashes. They aren't hard to use or understand at all once you understand the basic syntax

Answer (score 0):

**2.** `"ingredients/form"` isn't code--it's a string. It refers to the `_form` partial for the `ingredient` model. It's located in `app/views/ingredients/_form.erb.html`.

**3.** `:locals => { ... }` means the `render` function is getting a map entry with the symbol `:locals` as its key. `render` knows what to do with that map.

It's not "double assignment", it's that the value of the `:locals` key is *also* a map. `=>`, or the "hash rocket", is Ruby 1.8/1.9 syntax for assigning a map value to a map key. In Ruby 1.9 you can use a shortcut, `locals: { ... }`.

<sup>*(IMO which is more readable depends on the values--when the values are keys, I think the new syntax is heinous, otherwise I like it.)*</sup>

**4.** How is the signature difficult to understand? The argument is a hash of options.